# Is the localization of R by S is a subset of the ring R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, localization

Let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of a commutative ring $R$. Then is it true that the localization $R_S=\{r/s:r\in R, s\in S\}$ a sub-ring of $R$?

I think it is true, because $r/s=rs^{-1}$ and ring is closed under multiplication.
Am I right? Sorry, I know this is a trivial question, but I am just not sure. Thank you.

Comment: What is $s^{-1}$ when $s$ isn't invertible?  Your definition of the localization doesn't seem to make it clear what exactly $r/s$ actually means.  Is a fraction field $\operatorname{Quot}(R)$ of an integral domain $R$ a subring of $R$?

Comment: since $S$ is a manipulatively closed, is that means every element in $S$ is invertible?

Comment: No, even rings do not necessarily have their elements all multiplicatively invertible.  Take $\mathbb{Z}$ as an example.  It's fraction field, which is an example of the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, which is certainly not contained in $\mathbb{Z}$.  And what are the units of $\mathbb{Z}$?  Only $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, there is a (canonical) homomorphism $\varphi: R \to S^{-1}R$, such that $\varphi(x)=\dfrac x1$, which is injective if $S$ contains no zero-divisors. The best known example is the *field of fractions* of an integral domain, which certainly is not a subring of the domain (unless the latter be already a field, of course).